# Writing a C program to solve an equation numerically

Tags: linux, math

I am trying to solve *x-cos(x)=0* numerically.
I need the program to accept one argument on the command line that becomes the desired accuracy of the solution.
The solution should yield an answer within some +/- the specified accuracy (epsilon) of 0 when the equation *x-cos(x)* is evaluated.
The maximum number of iterations should be set to 100.
The program should start with a first guess value of x=0.
The desired accuracy should accept both floating and scientific notation formats.
There should be a warning message if too few or too many arguments are supplied, and therefore exit the program.
If a solution is found in the max iterations, it should print the solution, accuracy and number of iterations.
If no solution is achieved in the max iterations, the program should print a message to indicate as such and then close.

Find the smallest accuracy that can be achieved in max iterations in powers of 10.

I know that there are loops involved. I've started it as such:`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int MAX_ITERATIONS[100],x=0;
    float epsilon;
    double epsilon;

    x=cos[x];
    for (x=0; x<MAX_ITERATIONS; ++x) 
        if (MAX_ITERATIONS < x)
            x=MAX_ITERATIONS[100];
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here or if I am even on the right track.

Comment: You may want to consider stack overflow, as that is more programming related

Comment: Research Bisection method, False position method, Secant method, Newton's method. Probably one of them was mentioned before you got this task, use that one.

Comment: Newton's method is also called the Newton-Raphson method -- searching on that may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to help you get started.  My philosophy is to make only small changes and always keep a copy of what was working before.  The way when I break something, I know exactly where I broke it.  This code does not do everything you want, but you can make those changes yourself.  To compile the code, I used `cc -lm progname.c`.  To execute it, I used `./a.out 0.002`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double delta, x;
    double epsilon=0.001;
    double previous = 1.0;

    if (argc > 1)
        epsilon = strtof(argv[1], NULL);

    printf("Using epsilon = %12.8f\n", epsilon);

    for (x=0.1; x<1.0; x+=epsilon) {
        delta = fabs(x-cos(x));
        if (delta < previous)
            previous = delta;
        else
            break;
    }
    printf("%12.8f  %12.8f  %12.8f\n", x, cos(x), delta);

}
```

Comment: I know it's tempting to answer any question that you can, but please don't answer questions that are obviously, grossly off-topic for this site.